# Error if the [AssemblyInitialize] already exists in the test project with Specflow

Tags: mstest, specflow

I've updated Specflow from the `3.0.225` to the `3.1.62` and I received the error `Tests_Integration_MSTestAssemblyHooks: Cannot define more than one method with the AssemblyInitialize attribute inside an assembly.`

The reason is obviously that I'd had the `[AssemblyInitialize]` attribute in my project already. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that Specflow generates another file in the background which has the `AssemblyInitialize`/`AssemblyCleanup` hooks defined. In order to fix that one should use the hooks provided by Specflow, namely `BeforeTestRun`/`AfterTestRun`. Like this:

```
[Binding] // add the Binding attribute on the class with the assembly level hooks
public abstract class SeleniumTest 
{
  // it used to be [AssemblyInitialize]
  [BeforeTestRun]
  public static void AssemblyInitialize(/* note there is no TestContext parameter anymore */)
  {
    // ...
  }

  // it used to be [AssemblyCleanup]
  [AfterTestRun]
  public static void AssemblyCleanup()
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```